# AssociateColorProfileWithDevice, Where do you get the DeviceName?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371799(v=VS.85).aspx

So with a signature like this:

BOOL WINAPI AssociateColorProfileWithDevice(
    PCTSTR pMachineName,
    PCTSTR pProfileName,
    PCTSTR pDeviceName
);

pMachineName
Reserved. Must be NULL. This parameter is intended to point to the name of the machine on which to associate the specified profile and device. A NULL pointer indicates the local machine.

pProfileName
Points to the file name of the profile to associate.

pDeviceName
Points to the name of the device to associate.

pMachineName is suppose to be null, easy enough.
pProfileName is the file full file path, check.
pDeviceName, how do I get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EnumDisplayDevices` to all available display devices:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183569.aspx

Comment: While using that name the function returns true, when I check the setting in control panel it doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: Yes EnumDisplayDevice is the first step.
But what you need is the DeviceKey on the Display_Device object.